# Can't build product-iots-3.1.0-M7

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I tried to build WSO2 iot server 3.1.0-M7 in the following order

1. carbon-device-mgt-2.0.66
2. carbon-device-mtg-plugins-3.0.36
3. products-iots-3.1.0-M7

Step 1 and 2 built successfully, but the following exception was thrown when I build step 3.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test (default-test) on project org.wso2.carbon.iot.test.integration: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Error on initializing test environment
[ERROR] at org.wso2.carbon.automation.engine.testlisteners.TestExecutionListener.handleException(TestExecutionListener.java:71)
[ERROR] at org.wso2.carbon.automation.engine.testlisteners.TestExecutionListener.onExecutionStart(TestExecutionListener.java:52)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.runExecutionListeners(TestNG.java:1068)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1015)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:295)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[ERROR] at org.wso2.carbon.automation.engine.extensions.TestNGExtensionExecutor.executeExtensible(TestNGExtensionExecutor.java:75)
[ERROR] at org.wso2.carbon.automation.engine.testlisteners.TestExecutionListener.onExecutionStart(TestExecutionListener.java:47)
[ERROR] ... 8 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to start carbon server
[ERROR] at org.wso2.iot.integration.common.extensions.IOTServerExtension.handleException(IOTServerExtension.java:90)
[ERROR] at org.wso2.iot.integration.common.extensions.IOTServerExtension.onExecutionStart(IOTServerExtension.java:73)
[ERROR] ... 14 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Port 9763 is not open
[ERROR] at org.wso2.carbon.automation.extensions.servers.utils.ClientConnectionUtil.waitForPort(ClientConnectionUtil.java:248)
[ERROR] at org.wso2.carbon.automation.extensions.servers.carbonserver.CarbonServerManager.startServerUsingCarbonHome(CarbonServerManager.java:120)
[ERROR] at org.wso2.iot.integration.common.extensions.CustomTestServerManager.startServer(CustomTestServerManager.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.wso2.iot.integration.common.extensions.IOTServerExtension.onExecutionStart(IOTServerExtension.java:65)
[ERROR] ... 14 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I have the port as like the output of iptables.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:9443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:9763
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Any help would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to a unsuccessful shutdown of a service or another iot instance run on the given port. The failure is occurred when running maven tests according to the logs.

Please try again after killing all the unwanted processes manually.
Or you can trigger a maven build by skipping test runs by following the below maven command.

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Comment: Thanks Kachiex for your comment. It was a lot of help.